# CameraX is not configured properly. The most likely cause is you did not include a default implementation in your build such as 'camera-camera2

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

After updating from `androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha32` to `androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0-beta01` I receive the next error when using `CameraX`

```
camerax_version = "1.0.2"

// CameraX
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0-beta01"
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraX is not configured properly. The most likely cause is you did not include a default implementation in your build such as 'camera-camera2'.
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.<init>(CameraX.java:109)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.getOrCreateCameraXInstance(ProcessCameraProvider.java:181)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(ProcessCameraProvider.java:167)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It fails because you have different versions for the various androidx.camera.* libraries.

If you check this:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera

It has the following description:

> From 1.1.0-beta01, all CameraX libraries will align the same version
> number. This will help developers track versions much easier and
> reduce the complexity of large version compatibility matrix.

So you need to use the same version for ALL camerax libraries.

Comment: `Could not find androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.2` if using `camerax_version = "1.0.2"` for all deps

Comment: so I guess I need to use `1.1.0-beta01` for all libraries

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are using different api versions of same library , which couldn't find the new version of camera-camera2 api in the library .

```
val cameraVersion = "1.3.1"
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$cameraVersion")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$cameraVersion")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:$cameraVersion")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:$cameraVersion")
```

This code works well without any errors

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using camera2 but still getting this error just like in my case then just use the stable version of `1.3.1` for rest of the camera apis you need, instead of the `alpha-04` version as of now.